# Как правильно настроить удаленную отладку целевого устройства ARM64 в Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qtcreator, arm, gdb, remote-debugging

Пробую подключиться к целевому устройству под отладчиком, но все безуспешно. Вывод приложения такой:

```
14:51:07: Проверка доступных портов...
14:51:07: Обнаружен 51 свободный порт.
14:51:07: Запускается gdbserver --multi :10101...
14:51:07: Не удалось создать отладчик.
14:51:07: Пользователь запросил останов. Завершение...
Listening on port 10101
14:51:12: Истекло время ожидания завершения удалённого процесса.
```

Обычный удаленный запуск выполняется успешно. gdbserver на целевой машине установлен.

Comment: гм... а что __именно__ ты делаешь? [доки](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-operating-modes.html#using-gdb) креатора по удалённой отладке уже видел?

Comment: Есть плата на базе Rockchip rk3399, сейчас разрабатываю софтинку для нее. Смотрел документацию, но почему-то так не работает)

Comment: А по вашей ссылке, как я понимаю, решается обратная задача, запускается софт через gdbserver, а потом к нему можно подключиться отладчиком через хостовую машину.

Comment: не... я про то, как пытался прявязаться к удалённому отладчику (получив лог выше, как я понимаю)? кстати, не забыл, что потребуется получить или собрать кросс-gdb?

Comment: мм... да... а в чём тогда задача?

Comment: у меня есть подозрения, что нужно на целевом устройстве указать порт в gdbserver и сам gdbserver запустить, но как это делать не имею представления

Comment: лог я получил в креаторе при запуске отладчика

Comment: так... по порядку... на целевой железке ОСь есть?

Comment: мои ожидания: запустить отладку с хостовой машины и работать также, как если бы я отлаживался при разработке некроссплатформенной

Comment: на целевой стоит ubuntu 18.04

Comment: на хостовой тоже ubuntu

Comment: собственно вручную запускать на ней (целевой системе) `gdbserver` и к нему подключаться уже получается?

Comment: да, вручную запускается по примеру `gdbserver :1234 <executable>`

Упустил вопрос по кросс-gdb, я сам не собирал gcc, скачал aarch64, где также имеется gdb

Comment: подключение и вручную, и из креатора работает, правильно?

Comment: нет, подключиться так и не удалось, запустил gdbserver на целевом устройстве и он теперь просто слушает порт: 

`root@firefly:/tmp# gdbserver:10102 /opt/video_reader/bin/video_reader 
Process /opt/video_reader/bin/video_reader created; pid = 13860
Listening on port 10102`

потом на хост-машине в креаторе зашел в Отладка->Подключиться к серверу отладки..., там указал нужный комплект (aarch64), указал тот же порт, выбрал локал. программу ../video_reader (правда не вижу логики в этом..., но без этого креатор запуск вообще не разрешит), запустил, и

`10:59:04: Не удалось создать отладчик.`

Comment: сейчас через `Отладчик->Подключиться к порту QML...` получилось запустить отладку, но на целевом устройстве выводится
`...
Listening on port 10101
Remote debugging from host 192.168.2.57
Remote side has terminated connection.  GDBserver will reopen the connection.
Listening on port 10101
Remote debugging from host 192.168.2.57
Remote side has terminated connection.  GDBserver will reopen the connection.
...`

Comment: локальная программа gdb на стороне клиента нужна чтобы загрузить оттуда символы и отладичную информацию, так что это нормально... и она должна быть точно такая как и на удалённой тачке... «Подключиться к порту QML» — это что-то совсем другое и скорей всего тебя не интересует... проверь порты и адрес сервера, на которых gdbserver слушакт... накже проверь настройки комплекта... у меня получилось подкрутить креатора, чтобы нормально запускал удалённые команды и на отладку и просто на исполнение... и даже оказалось, что он умеет свежесобранные файлы заливать прямо на устрой…

Comment: сейчас всё расписывать не могу, так что до вечера...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел причину, по которой не мог выполнять отладку. Дело было в том, что используемый toolchain не имел в своем пакете средства отладки (вернее я использовал несколько компиляторов, но тот, что мне удобен - aarch64-linux-gnu, не имел отладчика). Я скачал отладчик gdb-multiarch и теперь отладка работает. Также проблема с отладкой может связана с отсутствием ssh-ключа, но это не точно.

```
sudo apt install gdb-multiarch
```

P.S.: *Можно было также дожать с тулчейном linaro...-linux-gnueabihf, т.к. там есть свой отладчик.*

Comment: зря я переживал, что ни как не могу собраться написать ответ =)